# Cleaning up InheritableThreadLocal when child threads are still running

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local, resource-cleanup

We are using `InheritableThreadLocal` in a web application at request level to store an `ApplicationContext` object that is used throughout the application.
There is a scenario for an async response wherein the request creates an acknowledgement ID and launches a child thread and returns the acknowledgement ID back. Finally, the `ThreadLocal` is removed.

However, the child thread seems to lose the ApplicationContext (is null) if it is running longer than the time it takes for the request to be processed.

Pseudo code:

```
doPost() {
 ApplicationContext ctx = createApplicationContext(req);
 MyThreadLocalContainer.setContext(ctx);
 new Thread(new RequestProcessor()).start(); // this seems to lose the ctx 
 MyThreadLocalContainer.removeContext();
}
```

Definition of MyThreadLocalContainer:

```
public class MyThreadLocalContainer {
 private static final ThreadLocal<ApplicationContext> APP_CTX = new InheritableThreadLocal<ApplicationContext>();
 public static void setContext(ApplicationContext ctx) {
   APP_CTX.set(ctx);
 }

 public static void removeContext() {
   APP_CTX.remove();
 }
}
```

How can the `ThreadLocal` cleanup be handled in this scenario without having to wait for the child thread to complete before calling `removeContext()`?

Comment: I think you want to use a subtype of `Phaser`, which both parent and child threads `register()` with when they start, and `arriveAndDeregister()` when they complete.  Phasers have a method `onAdvance()`, called when all registered parties arrive - you would override it in  your subtype to remove your context in it.

Comment: But wouldn't that cause the main thread to wait and not send the async response back until the child thread has terminated?

Comment: `arriveAndDeregister()` does not wait for others to complete, it returns immediately once the Phaser has recorded that this one is done, and deregisters it.   Eventually, the last associated with a given Phaser will call that method, and the `onAdvance()` method will be invoked at that point (I think by that last thread to call the arrive method?).  So every context would have a Phaser, all threads interested on a context would register with that Phaser when they start looking at the context, and deregister when they're done.